# How to prevent StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am able to find a few posts at SO related to this topic, but I am unable to find one related to my need.

I am using Spring MVC + JPA (Hibernate) for a website. In the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="deleteMyRecord", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void deleteQuestionAndUpdateLaterQuestions(HttpServletRequest request, 
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Long qid,
        Model model, Map<String, Object> map) {
    myService.deleteMyRecord(id);
}
```

The service layer method:

```
@Override
public void deleteMyRecord(Long id) { 
    myRecordRepository.delete(id); //using Spring Data
}
```

Only sometimes, the call to `myService.deleteMyRecord(id)` generates the StaleObjectStateException. I tried very hard and finally found out how it happened. This is how: When the website is slow, a user may be impatient and click the delete button twice. When both requests reach the service layer and the first request hasn't finished deleting the record, this exception happens when the second request calls `myService.deleteMyRecord(id)` after the first request calls it.

I am now looking for the solution. On the client side, I can disable the delete button once it is clicked. What can I do in the service layer or in controller to prevent this exception?

Comment: probably not much you can do on server side.  This is just like optimistic concurrency exception.  Either your service is intelligent enough to retry your action (and treat deleting a already-deleted record as success), or you simply provide meaningful message to client side saying that object state changed and trigger some kind of refresh to show the latest state.

Comment: There are other choice as attaching some kind of request ID in request (hence in your case, that impatient second delete request will bear same request ID) which allow you to ignore second/wait until first one to complete.  This involve bigger design change though, and you still need to deal case like with deleting same record from two different sessions

Comment: Adrian, thanks so much for your input!!!

Comment: Adrian, I am not sure whether there are other solutions. If we wait a few days and there are no further comments or answers, would you mind post your response as the answer? I will select it.